# Check if options(coming from the Json object) exists in select drop down

Tags: jquery, html, json

Two scenarios: the below two cases doesn't run at a same time. 
I have a select drop down with existing options, what I need to do is

1. Add 'selected' attribute to the option which matches with the key from the object. I don't need multiple selections here, I didn't know how to explain my actual scenario here hence I have used 'Batman' in the if condition if(jQuery(this).val() == "Batman"), in my scenario batman is dynamic.
2. If the keys doesn't match and doesn't exist in the DOM(select) then append that key as an option and the add 'selected' attribute.

I'm almost there but I couldn't figure out a solution without replacing all the values in the drop down(Please run the snippet). I have tried append option as well but couldn't get it right.

```js
var obj = {"characters": [{"Hulk": "Hulk"}]};
var opt;
$.each(obj["characters"], function(index, value) {
  $.each(value, function(val) {
    $('.sel-dropdwn').each(function() {
      if ($(this).find('option').val() == val)
        $(this).find('option').attr('selected', 'selected');
      else{
       opt = $('<option></option>');
       opt.text(val).val(val).attr('selected','selected');
       $(this).append(opt)
      }  
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select aria-required="true" class="form-control sel-dropdwn">
  <option value="">-- None --</option>
  <option value="Superman">Superman</option>
  <option value="Batman">Batman</option>
  <option value="Ironman">Ironman</option>
</select>
```

Comment: In a `select` element only one option can be `selected` at any point in time unless you add the `multiple` attribute (which your HTML doesn't have).

Comment: I have rewritten my question because I might not be clear, I need to include two scenarios 1.if the key from the object exists in the drop down then add select attribute  2. If the key doesn't exists then add/append it to the drop down. In this instance add 'Hulk' to the drop down and make it selected.

Comment: No need to 'add the selected attribute to an option'. $('select').val(value); will do that for you. You just need to see if the value you have already exists in the select or not. At the end, after adding new option (if needed) just set val() as the value.

Comment: **Several** of the objects from your JSON have a matching option. It is still unclear what your desired outcome is.

Comment: @connexo is right. Based on your example I understand you want to add hulk because it is not already in options. what if there were more than one options missing? On the other hand.. if hulk was already in the options.. which one will you select? if you say'hulk'.. then why?

Comment: @connexo, the example I took was bad, in the actual scenario that I'm facing only one option will match, I need to check if it's exists or not, if not append and select it. If the option already exists then add selected to it.

Comment: @NawedKhan I couldn't get the snippet right because it is very complicated to explain it here. There will be only one option that will match here.

Comment: Adjust your code then to match your scenario. After all your explanations it is **still** unclear. Did you mean you only receive one object in your JSON? If not, how are you dealing with more than one object that does not match? Do they all get added, and if so, which one you want selected?

Comment: So this means you are checking against one value, not a list of items. You have 'Hulk' at hand and you want to select hulk if it exists in list of options, or (if not exists) add and select it.

Comment: @NawedKhan yes, please explain me how to do it, that might be the closest thing to my case which might give me head start

Comment: @connexo I'm sorry for all this confusion, yes it will receive one object from json at a time. I will try to adjust the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comment and OP's clarification we understand that we want to select or add and select a given value.

```
let character = 'Hulk';
let exists = $('.sel-dropdwn option[value="'+ character + '"]').length > 0;

if(!exists){
   let option = $('<option value="'+ character + '"></option>').text(character);
   $('.sel-dropdwn').append(option);
}
$('.sel-dropdwn').val(character);
```

I am using a single value for character here. You may have an obj with key/value.